# How to use localStorage to store and get back user login details?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, ionic-framework, local-storage

I'm building a mobile app using the **[Ionic framework](http://ionicframework.com/)**, I need to be able to cache my user's login so they don't have to login every time.

I [read a solution](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-enable-remember-username-and-password-option-for-ionic-app-login-screen/10731) that recommends using [HTML5 localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html). However I'm unsure at the moment on how to implement it.

This is what my user login variables look like:

`credentials Object {username: "leon", password: "sushi"}`

And what my console.logs print out below:

[image]

#### My loginController:

```
// The Modernizr Code
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
    // window.localStorage is available!
    console.log('localStorage is available!');
    console.log('creds',creds);

} else {
    console.log('no native support for HTML5 storage :(');
    // no native support for HTML5 storage :(
    // maybe try dojox.storage or a third-party solution
}

// The Login function
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function login(credentials) {
    console.log('credentials',credentials);
    creds = localStorage["credentials"];
    console.log('creds',creds);
    AuthService.login(credentials).then(function (user) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess);

        if (user.password_reset) {
            $location.path('/password');
        }
        else {
            AuthService.saveUser(user);
            $location.path('/main');
        }

    }).catch(function () {
        vm.errorModalClosed = false;
        vm.loginError       = true;     
        PopupFactory.saveConfig("failure", "The username and password you entered don’t match.", true);
        $rootScope.$emit('open.popup');
    });
}
```

Comment: First you have to set the local storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

localStorage is global in the browser you can save data and then retrieve wherever you want, you add item like this `localStorage.setItem('key', 'value')` and getting localStorage.getItem('key');

Remember something, `localStorage` only save string, you have to use `JSON.stringify()` for save an object y `JSON.parse` for parsing to json again

in you specific example in the moment you save the user

```
AuthService.saveUser(user);
localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
$location.path('/main');
```

and retrieve in other place

```
var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
```

you can do that too inside your `AuthServer.saveUser(user)` and add some method like `AuthServer.getUser()` to get the user

Comment: Thanks! Got it working :D I know this is totally unsafe at the moment, but tokens will eventually replace the strings...